# bower ENOTFOUND Package pd-helpers: not found

Tags: polymer, bower, bower-install, bower-register, private-bower

Hi I am using below bower.json to build my application here we have pd-helpers dependecy where i am giving url and while running bower install its running succesfully if i change some version number of pd-helper or personal access token in bower.json and again running bower install then its saying bower ENOTFOUND  Package pd-helpers: not found

one thing i observe if i delete bower_component folder manually after my change and before running bower install then i am able to build successfully without above issue.

also whatever the version i am trying to change of pd-helpers in bower.json that is available in the github so there is not chance to think like that package version is not available there.

```
{
  "name": "predix-webapp-starter",
  "version": "^3.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "public/bower_components",
    "test",
    "sass",
    "tutorials"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "circular-json": "",
    "hopscotch": "^0.2.6",
    "polymer": "^1.6.1",
    "px-view": "^1.1.1",
    "app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#^0.9.1",
    "px": "^1.4.3",
    "px-card": "^0.6.1",
    "px-layout-design": "^0.4.3",
    "px-starter-kit-design": "^0.7.0",
    "px-theme": "^2.0.0",
    "px-view-header": "^0.2.0",
    "px-path-guide": "^0.0.2",
    "px-login": "^1.0.0",
    "px-context-browser": "^1.6.7",
    "iron-ajax": "~1.4.4",
    "px-data-table": "^2.1.3",
    "es6-promise": "~3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "px-rangepicker": "~1.3.10",
    "px-dropdown": "^3.1.1",
    "px-widths-responsive-design": "^0.4.4",
    "px-vis-timeseries": "^2.1.2",
    "px-app-nav": "^1.10.9",
    "px-spacing-design": "^0.4.4",
    "px-buttons-design": "^1.1.7",
    "marked-element": "^1.3.1",
    "px-dark-theme": "^1.0.10",
    "px-simple-bar-chart": "^1.9.1",
    "px-colors-design": "^0.3.0",
    "px-inbox": "^2.2.3",
    "px-widget-cards": "^3.0.4",
    "px-popover": "^2.0.9",
    "chart.js": "chartjs#^2.7.1",
    "pd-helpers": "https://51173769821ad2cd070cb59ea7b032b482569339:x-oauth-basic@github.build.ge.com/PD-MontBlanc/pd-helpers.git#1.1.0",
    "pd-alerts-inbox": "https://51173769821ad2cd070cb59ea7b032b482569339:x-oauth-basic@github.build.ge.com/SteamDigital/pd-alerts-inbox.git#cab3eadf07571acab5a117e33905a84e51da7128",
    "px-demo": "^3.1.2",
    "px-button-group-design": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "px-datetime-common": "^0.7.0",
    "app-localize-behavior": "^0.10.2",
    "iron-ajax": "^2.0.0",
    "px-theme": "^2.0.0",
    "px-colors-design": "^0.3.0",
    "px-defaults-design": "^1.0.2",
    "px-typography-design": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-icon": "^1.0.7",
    "iron-resizable-behavior": "^2.0.1",
    "px-popover": "^2.0.9",
    "promise-polyfill": "^1.0.0",
    "px-tooltip": "^1.0.0",
    "px-simple-chart-common-behavior": "^1.6.0",
    "iron-dropdown": "^1.5.4",
    "neon-animation": "^2.0.0",
    "px-d3-imports": "^1.0.1",
    "px-functions-design": "^1.0.0",
    "px-mixins-design": "^1.0.0",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "^1.0.9",
    "iron-flex-layout": "^1.0.0",
    "px-moment-imports": "^0.0.1",
    "px-number-formatter": "^3.0.4",
    "px-dropdown": "^4.0.0",
    "iron-a11y-keys": "^2.0.0",
    "px-card": "^0.6.1",
    "iron-overlay-behavior": "^2.2.0",
    "px-vis": "^2.0.0",
    "px-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "pxd3": "^4.7.0",
    "px-headings-design": "^0.3.1",
    "iron-location": "^0.8.1",
    "px-view-header": "^0.2.0",
    "px-deck-selector": "^2.0.0",
    "iron-fit-behavior": "1 - 2",
    "px-app-nav": "^1.10.9",
    "px-helpers-design": "^0.3.0",
    "px-buttons-design": "^1.1.7",
    "webcomponentsjs": "^0.7.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "px-button-group-design": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but polymer now uses npm instead of bower

Comment: we are using both npm install to install npm modules and bower install to install bower components